# Managing Drive File Visibility with Concurrent | Parallel access

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

In the context of the Google Drive API:

I need to implement a mechanism for generating temporary download links for files stored within my Google Drive organization account. These links should grant temporary public access to the file for a specific user, after which the file should revert to a private state. I am interested in achieving this process within Google's server infrastructure due to the anticipated volume of requests, which is expected to exceed 1000 requests. Executing this process on our own server *(getting the file metadata, storing in our server and then sending it to the client)* would impose significant costs. I am open to exploring more efficient methods if available. I'm an intern at the company and I'm charged to do this big task. Your insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

What I've tried myself, but I don't know about scalability // concurrent access to the same file etc:

```php
    /**
     * Gets the download link of a file
     * @param  string $fileId
     */
    public function getDownloadLink(string $fileId) {

        $this->setPermissionPublic($fileId);

        /**
         * @var \Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile $file
         */
        $file = $this->service->files->get(
            $fileId, 
            array('fields' => 'webContentLink')
        );
        
        return $file->getWebContentLink();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the file permission as public
     * @param  string $fileId id do arquivo.
     * @return void
     */
    private function setPermissionPublic(string $fileId) {
        $permission = new \Google\Service\Drive\Permission();
        $permission->setRole('reader');
        $permission->setType('anyone');
        $permission = $this->service->permissions->create($fileId, $permission);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the file permissions as private
     * @param string $fileId
     */
    public function setPermissionPrivate(string $fileId) {
        $this->service->permissions->delete($fileId, "anyoneWithLink");
    }
```

What the use case would be like:

```php
echo "Download: " . $fileController->getDownloadLink($fileId); //the echo here is just for testing

sleep(30); // trick, might be a trouble with paralell/concurrent access idk...

$fileController->setPermissionPrivate($fileId);
```

I've read the [Google Drive API REST resouce](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions?hl=pt-br) and found some interesting elements like `expirationTime`, but don't know how to use it and if it would fit in my specific use case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to implement a mechanism for generating temporary download links for files stored within my Google Drive organization account.

This functionality does not exist in the api.

> These links should grant temporary public access to the file for a specific user, after which the file should revert to a private state.

This functionality does not exist in the api.

> I am interested in achieving this process within Google's server infrastructure due to the anticipated volume of requests, which is expected to exceed 1000 requests. Executing this process on our own server (getting the file metadata, storing in our server and then sending it to the client) would impose significant costs.

Google drive is not a file hosting service. What you want to do is not posible with google drive or with the google drive api.

Comment: We're using Google Drive for it... Isn't the way I did a method to do so? By making the file temporarily public and then private again? Unfortunately, I'll have to find a way to do it with Drive... Or suggest my superior a new method to do so.

Comment: Tell your boss that you cant create temporary download or any links using the API this functionally doesn't exist.  Any link in the file itself will require that the user using the link have access to the file or the file be set to public.   Then tell them that files that are set to public are set to public for all users not a single user.   Finally let them know if they try to use the weblink or the download link for a file that is set to public more then say 200 times then google is going to give them an over usage error.    With all that said tell them to look into cloud storage.

Comment: All right... Got it. One more thing, do you have any suggestions on cloud storage?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage